# Reflection of velocity no longer works after converting to 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, physics

I've been making a game based on Dragon Quest Heroes Rocket Slime's tank battle system for a while. First thing I need to get down is it's movement system where the player can stretch and sling themselves in a direction. When they hit a wall they should reflect off it realistically (eg: hitting it diagonally will reflect them diagonally)

My game was in 2D for the most part but figuring out pseudo-3d collision in a 2D space among other issues made it nearly impossible to continue so I moved it to fully 3d.

Everything worked well until I tried bouncing off a wall. If my player hits a wall going up, he goes down and vice versa. However, if my player hits a wall going left it tries to 'reflect' him left when it should reflect him right (and vice versa for hitting it while going right).

The way 'velocity' works in my game is that when stretching a Vector2 called pVelocity goes up based on how much they stretched. When they let go a 'endPos' is created based on currentPosition + pVelocity. The player will then move via Vector3.MoveTowards to that endPos at a constant speed. When hitting a wall I do this:

```
if (hit && foundHit.transform!=transform && curState != state.wallHit && foundHit.transform.tag!="Object")
{
    //we've hit a wall while blasting

    //now we make the player 'squish' up against the wall and bounce off!

    Vector3 reflectedVelocity = Vector3.Reflect(new Vector3(pVelocity.x,0,pVelocity.y), foundHit.normal);

    //playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityX", reflectedVelocity.x);
    //playerAnimator.SetFloat("VelocityY", reflectedVelocity.y);

    curState = state.wallHit;
    playerSound.Play();
    transform.position = foundHit.point;

    playerAnimator.Play("Squish");
    StartCoroutine(wallBounce(reflectedVelocity));
}
```

And in wallBounce, I do this:

```
IEnumerator wallBounce(Vector3 hitVelocity)
{
    playerAnimator.enabled = true;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
    playerAnimator.Play("Walk blend tree");
    pVelocity = new Vector2(hitVelocity.x,hitVelocity.z);

    endPos = transform.position + (-transform.forward * pVelocity.magnitude);
    curState = state.blasting;

    Vector3 diff = endPos - transform.position;
    diff.Normalize();

    float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rot_z - 90, 0f);
}
```

When slinging, the player is always facing in the direction they're going so I assume that the issue is somewhere inside wallBounce when I create the new endPos but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was that my player wasn't looking in the direction of movement when hitting left or right. Adding this in the part before I call MoveTowards worked.

```
transform.LookAt(endPos);
```